# Channeled positron acceleration?

Tags: solid-state-physics, plasma-physics

Channeled positron acceleration?

Conduction electrons in a metal form a uniform high density plasma with longitudinal plasma oscillations. Charged particles are accelerated along atomic crystal channels by plasma waves in metal. Positively charged particles are guided by the average electric fields produced by atomic rows or planes in the crystal. The particles make a series of glancing collisions with many atoms and execute classical oscillatory motion along the interatomic channels.

For reference, see the article, "Channeled particle acceleration by plasma waves in metals" .

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-4187.pdf

So ultimately, the energy stored in the Coulomb fields of the nuclei of the atoms in metals is the energy that will accelerate the positrons to high velocities.

Basically, I want to know what would be the dominant phenomenon, electron - positron annihilation, or channeled acceleration of the positron in the crystal lattice? Is there an experimental setup where the positrons are accelerated with a minimum number of annihilation events?

Answer (score 1):

I found a recent paper (2015) [discussing the subject](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00387)  .

*TeV/m Nano-Accelerator: Investigation on Feasibility of CNT-Channeling Acceleration at Fermilab*

Chapter 2 discusses crystal channeling and concludes:

> The basic concepts  of  atomic  accelerator  with  short  pulse  driving  sources  like  high  power  lasers  or  ultra-short  bunches  have  been  considered  theoretically.  However,  the  idea  has  never  been
>   demonstrated by experiment or simulation 
>   due to the extremely tight interaction condition 
>   of  the  Angstrom-size  atomic  channels  in  natural  crystals  and  the 
>   complexity  of  electron
>   dynamics  in solid-plasma.

You ask:

> electron - positron annihilation, or channeled acceleration of the positron in the crystal lattice?

Until somebody undertakes to experiment with the idea it seems that it will be hard to guess which of the two will win, and whether the crystal will survive for long even if an accelerated beam comes through. My bets are in the annihilation winning.